# ESP32 SPI port control

Tags: c, arduino, esp32, spi

Since I can't control the VSPI and HSPI ports on ESP32 in particular, I tried to create a new instance of "hspi" based on the "SPI_multiple_buses.ino" example.Then I replaced SPI in the NRFlite library. transfer with hspi.transfer`.This is sketch part:

```
SPIClass * hspi = NULL;
NRFLite _radio;
RadioPacket _radioData;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    hspi = new SPIClass(HSPI);
    hspi->begin();`
```

I also replaced it in the .cpp file of the library, and library part:

```
 // Transfer with the Arduino SPI library.
        
        hspi->beginTransaction(SPISettings(NRF_SPICLOCK, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
        hspi->transfer(regName);
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            uint8_t newData = hspi->transfer(intData[i]);
            if (transferType == READ_OPERATION) { intData[i] = newData; }
        }
        hspi->endTransaction();
```

however, an error occurs while compiling: error: 'hspi' was not declared in this scope

I'm probably wrong somewhere but I don't know where?

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal sketch that demonstrates the problem. That will allow people who want to help to reproduce error you’re seeing. As it is, it’s possible the issue is in code you’ve omitted, and there’s not enough code to actually try to compile it.